# Calling a Stripe checkout form from a link rather than button on Leadpages

Tags: forms, button, customization, stripe-payments

Is there a way to modify the default Stripe Checkout script to work with a link element on a Leadpage?

If I use the default code it will place a blue button as standard over the existing button:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_ND6Tw8x8xxHBYNaBEAjZpBWq"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
</form>
```

I've tried using the custom button code, below, but from what I can see only an ID is allowed, not a class, which is how the link is coded.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_ND6Tw8x8xxHBYNaBEAjZpBWq',
    image: '/square-image.png',
    token: function(token) {
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    handler.open({
      name: 'Demo Site',
      description: '2 widgets ($20.00)',
      amount: 2000
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
</script>
```

Is there any way to get a link element on Leadpages to have the checkout script on it without involving  separate page on another site?

Answer (score 0):

The new example uses jQuery which makes it easier to find any element of your choice.

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

In your head tag tracking codes:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
```

In your end-of-body:

```
<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    // ... from example ...
  });

  $('.cta-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
    // ... your own info here ...
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
</script>
```

You'll have to figure out the right CSS selector, in the template I am looking at the button uses the "cta-btn" CSS class, so I put ".cta-btn" in as the target of the jQuery search.

Set the URL of the button to whatever you want, maybe this:

```
javascript:alert('Please enable Javascript or change browsers and try again.')
```

This should get the dialog to pop up.